# Full data not getting download kaggle

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, kaggle

I try to download complete dataset from kaggle which says just `kaggle competitions download -c rfcx-species-audio-detection` , then in order to get tfrecords separately I write this

```
import os, zipfile


dir_name = os.getcwd()
ext_loc = os.path.join(tf, 'train') 
#all train tfrecords files are ending with 148
extension = "148.tfrec.zip"

for item in os.listdir(dir_name): # loop through items in dir
    if item.endswith(extension): # check for "148.tfrec.zip" extension
        file_name = os.path.abspath(item) # get full path of files
        zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(file_name) # create zipfile object
        zip_ref.extractall(ext_loc) # extract file to dir
        zip_ref.close() # close file
        os.remove(file_name) # delete zipped file
```

After doing this I am getting 20 files but in the actual train dataset 31 files are present ,this means complete data is not getting downloaded. How to download complete data?

I do this in google-colab

Comment: Here is the link https://www.kaggle.com/c/rfcx-species-audio-detection/data

Comment: Can anyone try this on google colab and give hint as to how to get complete data in either flac or tfrec format , as I am eager to try the problem statement

Comment: it is big dataset - 57.32 GB - it needs time to download and always it can have problem to download it. Did you get error message when you try to download it?

Comment: last file has name `31-139.tfrec` instead of `31-148.tfrec`

Comment: @furas thanks for your interest no I don't get any error message , further `31-139.tfrec` is also not present in my content directory in colab

Comment: Google colab downloads `57.32 GB` in 3-4 mins , can you replicate this ?

Comment: I tested on Colab - I get also only 20 files - and the same with test data `63.tfrec.zip` - they should be 31 but I get 20. And when on kaggle I click link `31-148.tfrec.zip` then it download it without problem.

Comment: @furas , is this colab issue or kaggle or user and how to download complete data

Comment: @furas my computer storage is the double the size of database and so I can't download it directly , is there any way to get full data on colab

Comment: I still have free space on Colab and I didn't show any error message during download. But it downloaded 80 zip files and I didn't check  what else is in these files - maybe there are missing files.

Comment: @furas yes they download only few things in same directory and expects us to unzip and make directory from them

Comment: kaggle has own forum and maybe there will be some information -  https://www.kaggle.com/discussion - and every challange has own forum - https://www.kaggle.com/c/rfcx-species-audio-detection/discussion

Comment: @furas already asked but they reply only to data scientist  https://www.kaggle.com/c/rfcx-species-audio-detection/discussion/209954

Comment: I read `Data Description` on Kaggle and it seems you don't need these files - you need `.flac`

Comment: @furas it is optional one can work with flac or tfrecords , further even if you download flac files they are not dowloaded completely

Comment: when I start `kaggle` on Colab then it always says I use old version - maybe it make some problem - but I can't update it. Colab use Python 3.6 and it seems there is no newer version on `pip`

Comment: @furas So , is there no other work around?

Comment: kaggle has own servers similar to colab - I tested it and after creating Notebook I could select dataset from list and it was added in few seconds - in folder `/kaggle/input`. It seems it will be better idea then use Colab

Comment: @furas okay thanks a lot for your time and patience

Comment: I tested Notebook on Kaggle and I get all files - already unziped - in folder `/kaggle/input/rfcx-species-audio-detection`

Comment: @furas I had no idea about notebook , do they have tensorflow installed or we need to install through pip

Comment: @furas I can't give you points on comments but thanks a lot

Comment: I think `kaggle` will have all modules needed for `machine learning` and `neural network`.

Comment: @furas yes it has

Comment: I checked it has `tensorflow 2.3.1`. And when you create Notebooke then it asks if you want Python or R and only CPU or with GPU or TPU

Comment: @furas Thanks a lot man better than kaggle scientist community